# What does planar domains mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is related to the link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_spaces_for_planar_domains

In the above the Sobolev spaces is related to the planar domains. May I ask what exactly it means?

Answer (score 0):

This probably refers to an open bounded set $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^2$ whose boundary is smooth.

Comment: "planar domains" simply means a domain in a plane, it says nothing about smoothness.

Comment: @Yes I'm assuming from the context that there are some conditions assumed on $\Omega$.